# The .submit() function in JavaScript does not immediately submit the form on safari, leading to fields disabled after this is called not getting sent

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, onsubmit

I have a form on a website. Some of the html fields (they are `<select>` fields, if that is relevant) on this form are disabled to prevent the user sending changing the values in them, however, these need to be sent up to the server when the user submits the form. To do this, there is some JavaScript on the page that intercepts the submission event and stops it, enables the fields, submits the form, and then (for reasons I don't think are relevant) disables the fields again:

```js
function toggleDisableOnFields(areDisabled) {
  document.getElementsByName("x")[0].disabled = areDisabled;
  // other fields get enabled here too
}
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  toggleDisableOnFields(false);
  form.submit();
  toggleDisableOnFields(true);
});
```

On Chrome and Firefox, this works fine. The fields get enabled, the form gets submitted with their data included, and then the fields are successfully disabled again afterwards.

The issue is on Safari. The fields are enabled, the form submission happens, and the fields are disabled, but it seems as though the form only actually gets sent *after* they are disabled. Thus, their data is not sent up to the server as they are disabled by the time the request is sent.

If I remove the penultimate line of code:

```js
toggleDisableOnFields(true);
```

Then Safari sends the form complete with the data in these fields, confirming to me that the form is getting sent only after this line has run.

The question:
Why does the `.submit()` function send the form immediately on some browsers, but not on Safari?

**EDIT**

From experimentation it does not seem like the `submit()` is in itself asynchronous, as adding an `await` in front of it and making the wrapping method `async` does not solve the problem. I would *assume* this means it is a difference in how the browser handles the request to submit the form, rather than the code itself.

Comment: I am fairly positive disabled fields also get sent to the server, so the problem is likely something else. But let me check this to be certain.

Comment: Hi @SyedM.Sannan :)
So I was under this impression too but if I understand this correctly it appears not according to Mozilla: [HTML attribute: disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)  - "Browsers display disabled form controls greyed as disabled form controls are immutable, won't receive focus or any browsing events, like mouse clicks or focus-related ones, and aren't submitted with the form."

Comment: Just took a look, it looks like you are correct. It might sound like a weird idea, but we are only experimenting with this at the moment I guess, but how about you create a `setTimeout` of say, 1000 ms, and put the form disabling code inside it?

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan I am fairly certain this would work, but I will try it to be sure and get back to you. The route we have gone with is to simply remove the disabling code, but my question is more about why this happens on Safari but not on other browsers, rather than potentially solutions to the problem, if that makes sense? I appreciate the help though :)

Comment: One thing seems wierd to me. You have listener on form submit event. So, something/someone submits the form, listener handler gets triggered, do some disabling magic and submits the form again, which triggers the handler again and the recursion runs forever, until browser explode. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @Mono, I appreciate the comment. As I understand it from these [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit), no submit event is raised when calling the `submit()` method, so this should only run when the user clicks the button manually. To be fair, though, I have not tested this to see if it is the case.

Comment: If your capturing the `onSubmit` with `preventDefault`,  it's normally the case you then manually submit the data say using `fetch`, the problem here is likely that `submit` is `async`, and there is no easy way to wait for this to finish, you could maybe using a `setTimeout` to re-disable, but that would feel a bit hacky, if you use `fetch` you can know when the submit has finished, so I would recommend that.  Also if you use `fetch` you won't need to worry about disabling and enabling, as you will be forming the payload anyway.

Comment: Hi @Keith, thanks for the comment. fetch is another good workaround for the problem! We have a successful workaround in place now, my question is more driven out of curiosity as why this would happen only on Safari and whether there is documentation about this behaviour anyway :)